# How to change default activity in Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I used to use this apk a few months ago for studying and the last few days I've tried using it again but since I used it last time the app login system broke.
It used an login page for leaderboards and 1vs1 quizes but i dont need those features, i just need the learning environment.

But in order to get to the learning environment you have to log in, and since the log in doesn't work anymore I decided to take matters into my own hands and edit the app to bypass the login page, I've done my research and fell into a rabbit hole for 8 hours today and now i finally gave up.

This is part of the AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.UMFQuizApp" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>
        <activity android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.login.AuthenticationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.login.FirstActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.login.RegisterActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.login.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.main.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.ModeSelectionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme"/>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/training_mode" android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.testselection.training.TrainingSelectActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/exam_mode" android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.testselection.exam.ExamSelectActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_quiz" android:name="ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.quiz.types.exam.QuizExamActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

I used a 3rd party app to find what name does the login page have, and the name is "ro.umfquiz.umfquiz.presentation.login.AuthenticationActivity".
I learned that the activity with the intent-filter that has action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER is the activity that launches by default, i have tried moving that intent-filter tag to MainActivity, then to ModeSelectionActivity, FirstActivity, etc and none of this worked, i still landed on the login page. After moving the intent tag i always recompiled signed and reinstalled the apk and also made sure the changes were saved.

I also tried using android:enabled="false" on a lot of activities related to login, that version failed to sign .. idk?

So please help me, i really need this app to work. here is the apk, you can check it for viruses if you dont trust me but i guarantee that is safe.

The tools i used were : apktool, MT Manager, apk-signer, Current Activity, Notepad ++.

Link to apk : [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12dMg9bzQC_g-LwEY5PBX-sDuedhPFXO7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi @Panda, do you have the source code with you somewhere. The APK file provided is not of much use without the source code.

Comment: no.. i only have the apk

Comment: So you can't bypass login page without source code? I saw plenty of guys on ytb doing this, were they just trolling?

Answer (score 0):

TO change the default activity you just move the code that says

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

to the activity you want.  Now whether the app will work after you do that-  it depends on if it needed data from that login server, and if its coded defensively to not crash if it can't reach their servers.  Most likely it will crash, either immediately or after some time when it attempts to access data it needed from the server.  But you may be able to use some of the app without it, it depends on a lot of factors in how they code it and how the app works.

Comment: The login screen has the name AuthenticationActivity and as you can see, in the default manifest those intent tags aren't on the AuthenticationActivity, they are on the MainActivity but still it opens to AuthenticationActivity automatically...

Comment: @PandaYTCANALVECHI Then there's code in the MainActivity which launches AuthenticationActivity if you aren't logged in.  That's fairly common, so if for some reason the app is relaunched from an inner activity and you aren't logged in, it will force you to log in.  The only way to fix that is to actually edit the code, not just the manifest.  And it makes it much more likely the app will just crash without being logged in, they wrote it with the assumption you must be logged in.

Comment: Yes.. I have played around with manifest and now it opens past the login screen for half a second and then it forces me back to login. Is there a way I can delete this forwarding or idk

Comment: Could there be code on every activity to check if I'm logged in? I m thinking if I edit the smali files I can find the check for logged in and make it always true, isn't that right ?

Comment: I have found an function isLoggedIn in a .dex file and changed it so that it always returns a 1 and now I have bypassed the login screen

Comment: I can chose any activity to open by default and it doesn't forward me to the login screen but now buttons either do not work or crash the app...

Comment: You've gone about as far as you can-  if the buttons aren't working or are crashing, they're trying to use data you don't have.  Going any farther is going to be a matter of patching each crash by hand to either not make the call that crashes it, or to fake out data.

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
        <activity android:name=".Your_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```